# count function sql

Tags: sql, oracle

The relational schema for the `Academics` database is as follows:

```
DEPARTMENT (deptnum, descrip, instname, deptname, state, postcode)
ACADEMIC (acnum, deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)
PAPER (panum, title)
AUTHOR (panum*, acnum*)
FIELD (fieldnum, id, title)
INTEREST (fieldnum*, acnum*, descrip)
```

For each academic, return the `acnum, givename, famname` and the total number of papers s/he has written.

Note that if an academic has not written any paper, his/her total should be zero.

You can use JOIN operators such as NATURAL, JOIN ...ON.

I can't seem to figure out this SQL query. The count area is where I'm having trouble. My code is below - I've been struggling with this for a few hours.

```
select
    acnum,
    givename,
    famname,
    count(panum)
from 
    academic 
natural join 
    author
```

Comment: Hint: Take a look at Group By

Comment: i use a group by at the end of the query?

Comment: Yes at the end. Just like the answer by @zealous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you posted, this might be what you're looking for:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  academic (acnum, famname, givename) as
  4    (select 1, 'Smith', 'John'   from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'Tiger', 'Smith'  from dual union all   --> no published papers
  6     select 3, 'Foot' , 'Little' from dual
  7    ),
  8  author (panum, acnum) as
  9    (select 100, 1 from dual union all
 10     select 200, 3 from dual
 11    )
 12  -- query you need begins here
 13  select a.acnum,
 14         a.famname,
 15         a.givename,
 16         count(t.panum)
 17  from academic a left join author t on a.acnum = t.acnum
 18  group by a.acnum,
 19           a.famname,
 20           a.givename
 21  order by a.acnum;

     ACNUM FAMNA GIVENA COUNT(T.PANUM)
---------- ----- ------ --------------
         1 Smith John                1
         2 Tiger Smith               0
         3 Foot  Little              1

SQL>
```

---

Error you got

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

was caused by the `count` function's parameter. If you used a tool that actually *shows* where it (the error) happened, you'd see it yourself. For example, SQL*Plus is such a tool:

```
<snip>
 12  -- query you need begins here
 13  select a.acnum,
 14         a.famname,
 15         a.givename,
 16         count(t.*)
 17  from academic a left join author t on a.acnum = t.acnum
 18  group by a.acnum,
 19           a.famname,
 20           a.givename
 21  order by a.acnum;
       count(t.*)              --> this caused
               *               --> the error!
ERROR at line 16:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification


SQL>
```

Comment: that works! i also want to find the deptnum, depntname, instname where an academic doesnt have a research interest. Do i use a non exist subquery?

Comment: NOT EXISTS or NOT IN might be your choices; try it.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work, you need a `left join` to get all academic and `group by` for aggregation.

```
select
    ac.acnum,
    givename,
    famname,
    coalesce(count(au.*), 0) as total_papers
from academic ac

left join author au
on ac.acnum = au.acnum

group by
    ac.acnum,
    givename,
    famname
```

Comment: this is throwing an error as follows: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 28 Column: 23

Comment: im sorry still getting the same error  ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 65 Column: 23

Comment: i also want to find the  deptnum, depntname, instname where an academic doesnt have a research interest. Do i use a non exist subquery?

Comment: it did not. i used a natural join with the group by @zealous

Comment: it was the same error as previously posted @zealous

Comment: @taathtwostep check column names are correct in the query?

Comment: its correct @zealous. can you help me with the question in the comments above please?